# Simplifying Radical Expression $\frac{\sqrt[3]{3a^4}}{\sqrt[3]{7b^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{3a^4}}{\sqrt[3]{7b^2}}$$

I don't know how to simplify this. Everything I try to do just ends up with me taking out a single $a^3$. I tried a [search](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3a%5E4%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B7b%5E2%7D%7D) on Wolfram Alpha but it didn't yield anything useful.

Comment: This can't be simplified further, unless you don't mind fractional exponents and surds, but that isn't exactly a simplification, it's just ornamentation, like tidying up the expression as if it were a bridegroom.

Comment: You can't do much better than $a \sqrt[3]{3\; 7^{-1} \;a \;b^{-2}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{3a^4}}{\sqrt[3]{7b^2}}=
\left(\frac37\right)^\frac 13\left(\frac {a^2}b\right)^\frac23
=\left[\frac 37\left(\frac{a^2}b\right)^2\right]^\frac13$$
Different variations. Not necessarily simplified.